# Ways to define ocaml function

Tags: ocaml

I tried to define function which type is

`(test, test) -> test`.

So I wrote down my code like this :

`let test_func: (test, test) -> test = fun ...`

But It gave me syntax error, so I changed it to

`let test_func: (test, test) test = fun ...`

And It doesn't give me syntax error message.

But I don't know why the first one gives me the syntax error..

(I also tried this form. `let test_func (test, test): test` Is this the better way to define function?)

Comment: Also, this is the third question you post where you demonstrate a lack of understanding of how functions work in OCaml, despite having it explained several times. Perhaps you should review your course material to make sure you understand how curried functions work, or ask a teacher or someone who can guide you through it step by step. Stack Overflow really does not work very well as a tutorial service.

Comment: `let test_func: (test, test) test = fun ...` also can never have compiled because the type `test` can not expect both 2 arguments (at the end) and 0 arguments (inside the parents).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(test, test)` isn't a valid type. If your intent is to describe a tuple type, the right syntax is `test * test`. I suspect you actually want to describe a function with two arguments, however, which would be `test -> test -> test` because OCaml is a curried language.

`(test, test) test` is syntactically valid because it describes a parameterized type that's given two arguments.

`let test_func (test, test): test` does not specify the entire function type, just the return type. `(test, test)` here describes a single tuple argument where the items are bound to `test` and `test` respectively. I'm guessing you're actually using different names though, otherwise this wouldn't compile.

You can specify the type of each argument and the return type separately like this:

```
let test_func (a: test) (b: test): test = ...
```